Brightway2.5 backend format for .write_exchanges()
Importing a IO table in Brightway2.5 with IOTableBackend.
.write() works but I can't figure out .write_exchanges(). Documentation says: Technosphere and biosphere data has format (row id, col id, value, flip).
Example:
data = {
    ("bedb", "act1"): {
        "name": "sadkj",
        "unit": "aaa",
        "location": "GLO",
        "type": "product",
        "format": "some_format",
        "key": ("bedb", "act1"),
    },
    ("bedb", "act2"): {
        "name": "askdj",
        "unit": "bbb",
        "location": "GLO",
        "type": "product",
        "format": "some_format",
        "key": ("bedb", "act2"),
    },
}

bedb = bd.backends.iotable.IOTableBackend('bedb')
bedb.write(data) # all good

I have then tried various types of technosphere formats like:
technosphere = [
      (("bedb", "act1"), ("bedb", "act1"),  1.0, False),
      (("bedb", "act1"), ("bedb", "act2"), 0.5, True),
      (("bedb", "act2"), ("bedb", "act2"),  1.0, False),
      (("bedb", "act2"), ("bedb", "act1"), 0.5, True),
      ]

technosphere = [
      (("bedb", 0), ("bedb", 0),  1.0, False),
      (("bedb", 1), ("bedb", 0), 0.5, True),
      (("bedb", 1), ("bedb", 1),  1.0, False),
      (("bedb", 1), ("bedb", 0), 0.5, True),
      ]
    
technosphere = [(0, 0, 1.0, False),
                 (0, 1, 0.5, True),
                 (1, 1, 1.0, False), 
                 (1, 0, 0.5, True)]

(Same for biosphere, I tried similar formats. For the reproducible example here: biosphere = [] and dependents = [])
None of them seems to work with bedb.write_exchanges(technosphere, biosphere, dependents) I always get a TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
What is the right format?

Turns out, the documentation is perhaps a bit misleading as the argument of write_exchanges() is not literally in this format (row id, col id, value, flip).
After bedb.write(data) using [node['id'] for node in bedb if node['type'] == 'product'] returns [6, 7] these are the coordinates for the two activities (nodes),
Doing this creates the right data for import:
t_data = np.array([1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.3]) # technosphere data
t_indices = np.array([(6,6), (6,7), (7,7), (7,6)],dtype=bwp.INDICES_DTYPE)
t_flip = np.array([False if i[0] == i[1] else True for i in t_indices ]) 

b_data = np.array([123, 456, 2, 2]) # biosphere data
b_indices = np.array([(6,0), (6,1), (7,1), (7,0)],dtype=bwp.INDICES_DTYPE)
b_flip = np.array([False for i in b_indices]) 

Once formatted into a dictionary:
technosphere = {'indices_array' : t_indices,
    'data_array' : t_data,
    'flip_array' : t_flip}

biosphere = {'indices_array' : b_indices,
    'data_array' : b_data,
    'flip_array' : b_flip}

dependents = []

The data can be used here:
bedb.write_exchanges(technosphere, biosphere, dependents)

lca = bc.LCA(demand={ bedb.get('act1'): 1})
lca.lci()

I am not sure if this is the recommended way to link metadata with datapackage  exchanges with IOTableBackend but at least seems to work.
